# Adding custom-content block to Shopify footer

Tags: liquid

This theme only allowed for 'text' and 'links' blocks in the footer. So, we changed it and added a 'logo' block and then a 'custom-content' block. The schema for the custom-content block works and I can input the custom-content for this block that is supposed to show in the footer area. But, the output does not appear in the footer area. I limited the number to 1; still it doesn't work. Then, searched all of the docs & tutorials I could find, but could not fix the problem. Help would be appreciated.

```
  "type": "html",
  "limit": 1,
  "name": {
    "cs": "Vlastní HTML",
    "da": "Tilpasset HTML",
    "de": "Personalisierte HTML",
    "en": "Custom HTML",
    "es": "HTML personalizado",
    "fi": "Mukautettu HTML",
    "fr": "HTML personnalisé",
    "hi": "कस्टम HTML",
    "it": "HTML personalizzato",
    "ja": "HTMLをカスタムする",
    "ko": "사용자 지정 HTML",
    "nb": "Tilpasset HTML",
    "nl": "Aangepaste HTML",
    "pl": "Niestandardowy HTML",
    "pt-BR": "HTML personalizado",
    "pt-PT": "HTML personalizado",
    "sv": "Anpassa HTML",
    "th": "HTML แบบกำหนดเอง",
    "tr": "Özel HTML",
    "vi": "HTML tùy chỉnh",
    "zh-CN": "自定义 HTML",
    "zh-TW": "自訂 HTML"
  },
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "html",
      "id": "code",
      "label": {
        "cs": "HTML",
        "da": "HTML",
        "de": "HTML",
        "en": "HTML",
        "es": "HTML",
        "fi": "HTML",
        "fr": "HTML",
        "hi": "HTML",
        "it": "HTML",
        "ja": "HTML",
        "ko": "HTML",
        "nb": "HTML",
        "nl": "HTML",
        "pl": "HTML",
        "pt-BR": "HTML",
        "pt-PT": "HTML",
        "sv": "HTML",
        "th": "HTML",
        "tr": "HTML",
        "vi": "HTML",
        "zh-CN": "HTML",
        "zh-TW": "HTML"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "width",
      "label": {
        "cs": "Šířka kontejneru",
        "da": "Containerbredde",
        "de": "Breite des Elements",
        "en": "Container width",
        "es": "Ancho del contenedor",
        "fi": "Säiliön leveys",
        "fr": "Largeur du conteneur",
        "hi": "कंटेनर की चौड़ाई",
        "it": "Larghezza contenitore",
        "ja": "コンテナーの幅",
        "ko": "컨테이너 폭",
        "nb": "Beholderbredde",
        "nl": "Containerbreedte",
        "pl": "Szerokość kontenera",
        "pt-BR": "Largura do contêiner",
        "pt-PT": "Largura do recipiente",
        "sv": "Container-bredd",
        "th": "ความกว้างของความจุ",
        "tr": "Kapsayıcı genişliği",
        "vi": "Chiều rộng khoảng chứa",
        "zh-CN": "容器宽度",
        "zh-TW": "容器寬度"
      },
      "default": "50%",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "25%",
          "label": {
            "cs": "25 %",
            "da": "25 %",
            "de": "25%",
            "en": "25%",
            "es": "25%",
            "fi": "25 %",
            "fr": "25 %",
            "hi": "25%",
            "it": "25%",
            "ja": "25%",
            "ko": "25%",
            "nb": "25 %",
            "nl": "25%",
            "pl": "25%",
            "pt-BR": "25%",
            "pt-PT": "25%",
            "sv": "25 %",
            "th": "25%",
            "tr": "%25",
            "vi": "25%",
            "zh-CN": "25％",
            "zh-TW": "25%"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": "33%",
          "label": {
            "cs": "33 %",
            "da": "33 %",
            "de": "33%",
            "en": "33%",
            "es": "33%",
            "fi": "33 %",
            "fr": "33 %",
            "hi": "33%",
            "it": "33%",
            "ja": "33%",
            "ko": "33%",
            "nb": "33 %",
            "nl": "33%",
            "pl": "33%",
            "pt-BR": "33%",
            "pt-PT": "33%",
            "sv": "33 %",
            "th": "33%",
            "tr": "%33",
            "vi": "33%",
            "zh-CN": "33%",
            "zh-TW": "33%"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": "50%",
          "label": {
            "cs": "50 %",
            "da": "50 %",
            "de": "50%",
            "en": "50%",
            "es": "50%",
            "fi": "50 %",
            "fr": "50 %",
            "hi": "50%",
            "it": "50%",
            "ja": "50%",
            "ko": "50%",
            "nb": "50 %",
            "nl": "50%",
            "pl": "50%",
            "pt-BR": "50%",
            "pt-PT": "50%",
            "sv": "50 %",
            "th": "50%",
            "tr": "%50",
            "vi": "50%",
            "zh-CN": "50%",
            "zh-TW": "50%"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": "66%",
          "label": {
            "cs": "66 %",
            "da": "66 %",
            "de": "66%",
            "en": "66%",
            "es": "66%",
            "fi": "66 %",
            "fr": "66 %",
            "hi": "66%",
            "it": "66%",
            "ja": "66%",
            "ko": "66%",
            "nb": "66 %",
            "nl": "66%",
            "pl": "66%",
            "pt-BR": "66%",
            "pt-PT": "66%",
            "sv": "66 %",
            "th": "66%",
            "tr": "%66",
            "vi": "66%",
            "zh-CN": "66%",
            "zh-TW": "66%"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": "75%",
          "label": {
            "cs": "75 %",
            "da": "75 %",
            "de": "75%",
            "en": "75%",
            "es": "75%",
            "fi": "75 %",
            "fr": "75 %",
            "hi": "75%",
            "it": "75%",
            "ja": "75%",
            "ko": "75%",
            "nb": "75 %",
            "nl": "75%",
            "pl": "75%",
            "pt-BR": "75%",
            "pt-PT": "75%",
            "sv": "75 %",
            "th": "75%",
            "tr": "%75",
            "vi": "75%",
            "zh-CN": "75%",
            "zh-TW": "75%"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": "100%",
          "label": {
            "cs": "100 %",
            "da": "100 %",
            "de": "100%",
            "en": "100%",
            "es": "100%",
            "fi": "100 %",
            "fr": "100 %",
            "hi": "100%",
            "it": "100%",
            "ja": "100%",
            "ko": "100%",
            "nb": "100 %",
            "nl": "100%",
            "pl": "100%",
            "pt-BR": "100%",
            "pt-PT": "100%",
            "sv": "100 %",
            "th": "100%",
            "tr": "%100",
            "vi": "100%",
            "zh-CN": "100%",
            "zh-TW": "100%"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code or any related screenshot which give us some more info? Thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, just updated the question for you with the code of the schema used.

Comment: Would you please show us code of footer display?

Comment: Hi Alice, tried various alternatives of the following:  <div class="site-footer_html">{{ block.settings.html_code }}</div>  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After checking your updated question. I realized that you are not correctly getting the value of your custom html block.

You are trying to get the value using:

`<div class="site-footer_html">{{ block.settings.html_code }}</div>`

But according to your Scheme code the ID is "code" not "html_code". You need to get the value using:

`<div class="site-footer_html">{{ block.settings.code}}</div>`

Comment: Thank you, that's correct! But, in addition:  a 'when' clause needs to come before this to make it work.